# 'id' is always undefined (Leap motion)

Tags: javascript

I have just started to develop for Leap motion, and i have general question Here is my code:

```
    Leap.loop(function(obj) {
       var hands = obj.hands.map(function(d) {
        return {
          id: d.id,
          length: d.length,
          palmPositionX: d.palmPosition[0],
          palmPositionY: d.palmPosition[1],
          palmPositionZ: d.palmPosition[2]
        }

      });
 console.log(hands.length); //Work fine
 console.log(hands.id); //undefined!

     //handParcoords.data(hands).render(); //This works - It takes all parameters and render a chart

    });
```

Am I missing something? Why does the length work when the id and palmPositionX or palmPositionY don't?

Comment: do a var_dump(d) before the return { to see the state of the object passed in.

Answer (score 4):

`hands` is an array so you'll have to reference an element in the array then get its id

```
console.log(hands[0].id);
```

Comment: sorry, But its not correct in this case, it running in loop and the array is not int the '0' position, Here is the leap.hands api: http://js.leapmotion.com/api/v0.2.0/ it might help, I'm appreciate that anyway!

Comment: From your link there is no `map` method on the hand object, so I assumed it was from `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: Thanks!, i guess you right, so dont you saw anything in the hand object related this problem?? Thank you again!

Comment: @user2466914 what do you get when you do a `console.log(hands);`

Comment: I've tried, i get nothing :( i guess i need to read the full API to understand where is the problem.. Thanks anyway..